# Meaning of "Two sections a pop"

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

The article talks about "[paper airplane folding gun](http://makezine.com/2014/11/13/tinkerer-builds-gun-that-folds-and-fires-paper-airplanes/)", which takes sheets of paper as ammo, folds them into paper airplanes using a series of rollers, and launches them through the front. But the article uses an expression I don't understand.

> The maker behind the project is keeping his lips sealed, but a video featuring the gun in action is currently available on YouTube. The gun can fold and fire paper airplanes in about **two sections a pop**, so watch out backyard gamers – these are dangerous patches of grass.

What does it mean?

Comment: Probably, it's a typo of "two seconds a pop".

Comment: Agree, with the further explanation that 'a pop' means something like 'for each'.

Comment: To support the typo-theory, the article also states "[the machine] **folks** [paper] into quality paper airplanes". It almost looks like at least part of the article was written on a phone with the autocorrect function turned on :)

Comment: The correct and idiomatic way to say this would be "The gun can fold and fire paper airplanes **at** about two **seconds** a pop."

Comment: Thanks - I guess this is the answer and if you post that as one, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the article and watching the clip, I believe that the prevailing theory of ***sections*** being a typo of ***seconds*** is absolutely correct (espoused by Darnkerng T., SydneyAustraliaESLTeacher, oerkelens and Jason Patterson).

And, as stated by Sydney, ***two seconds a pop*** would indeed mean "taking two seconds for each."

Sadly, you can look forward to many more typos in online articles and news sources as the rush to get content out means that things like proofreading and fact-checking are the among the first casualties sacrificed upon the altar of expediency...